# Get Specific Word using Bash Scripting

Tags: bash

I'm a newbie to shell scripting.

Now I want to get specific word from a string, that is: "2012-10-10 14:00"

```
#! /bin/bash
var="   user active 2012-10-10 14:00"

#how to get 2012-10-10 14:00 ?

echo $var
```

How to get that specific string?
Thank you for helping :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameter expansion:

```
when=${var#*active }
echo "$when"
```

`#` removes characters from the beginning of the string up to the pattern given.